# Missing Styles on a repeated element?

Tags: css, css-float

I'm working on a jQuery Grid and List view. List view is fine, This was already built as default. The problem I'm having is the Grid View.

Example is : [here](http://dev.lceonline.co.uk/test)

As you can see when clicking on Grid View. The "Add to Cart, Quantity and SKU Code" only load for the one product.

I'm suspecting its something to do with the absolute positioning? Could be wrong. But if anyone can point me in the right direction to correct this, So that this is repeated for **ALL** elements, would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: i can't see what you mean. I have to "Add to cart" for every product

Comment: oh sorry... didnt see the button ;)

Comment: Ah ha! Was fearing I'd not replicated my issue there

Comment: @StuBlackett, IMO, your approach is a bit complicated - the said layout can be be achieved easily using `inline-block` for grid generation. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5mkh8/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to remove `position:absolute` from following classes:

```
.buy-now
.buynowprices
```

Comment: Excellent, Thanks for clicking the button ;)